# Best way to expose API on the front-end with ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript

**I want to know the best way to expose my server's API to my front-end web app**. I know I could place all the code in just one file and it'd work. But I want to know a more organized way to expose it. So **I came up with two ideias**:

**First:** Export a *module named API and this module export its sub modules* like Authentication module, users, tasks... The problem with this aproach is that **I couldn't find a way to make dotted imports** like import { API.authenticate }, I need to import all things from api and then access the object.

```
import { authenticate } from "./src/authenticationService.module.js";
import { users } from "./src/usersSerivice.module.js";
import { tasks } from "./src/tasksSerivice.module.js";
import { projects } from "./src/projectsSerivice.module.js";
import { projectSteps } from "./src/projectStepsSerivice.module.js";

export const API = { authenticate, users, tasks, projects, projectSteps };
```

authentication.module.js;

```
import { API } from "../backend/api.module.js";

API.authenticate.login("email", "pass");
```

**Second:** *A module for each endpoint* like AuthenticationAPI, UsersAPI, TasksAPI... but the problem is that **I think I'm creating to much repetitive** module names.

An example:

```
export const authenticateAPI = { login };
```

authentication.module.js

```
import { authenticateAPI } from "../backend/authentication-api.module.js";

authenticateAPI.login("email", "pass");
```

Is any of these a good approach or you suggest a better one? I'm new to programming.

Comment: technical nit: it's just "ES modules". ES6 was five years ago. Also if you want to import as `import { API } from`, you want `import ... from ... ; ...; const API = { authenticate, users, tasks, projects, projectSteps }; export { API }` instead. Don't put an assignment in an export.

Comment: I would recommend checking out GraphQL (or REST) and build to types. There's also tools like [MirageJS](https://miragejs.com/) that help you mock your http interfaces so you don't build out a bunch of stuff you may not need. There's also Prisma.js, https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/authentication, which has a whole organizational scheme.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Ok, thanks for your tips. But if export as so, I can't import just the api serivice I need. I'll need to import all! Is there a way to make it better?

Comment: @JaredFarrish In the future I'll learn about GraphQL but for now I want to learn the basics, have a very solid basis and then start to go to more advanced stuffs. I'll take a look at these projects. Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand. You _define_ API yourself, in that first file. So define it as `const API = { ...., ..., ..., ..., ...};` and then follow that up with `export { API }`. With that simple change you can now import from that file using the `import { API } from "yourfile.js";` that you show in your second file.

Comment: The problem is this will import all the functions declared in the export  like authenticate, users, tasks, projects, projectSteps. But I just need one of those. Isn't it a wast of performance?

Comment: You can try Webpack's [treeshaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).